# How to use Firebase built-in features instead of ORM?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, orm

I started using Firebase for Android app with Kotlin. So the question is how to use Firebase built-in features instead of adding ORM? I would like to work with classes and objects, instead of dealing with get, set, onSuccessListener and other firebase methods.. So I can create some semi-ORM by myself, by dividing everything to adapter and models. However is there simpler solution? I assume there should be some built in features in Firebase?
E. g. we can query documents with Firebase functions and map them to classes as per [official manual](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#kotlin+ktx_1):

```
val docRef = db.collection("cities").document("BJ")
docRef.get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot ->
    val city = documentSnapshot.toObject<City>()
}
```

To make controller loose coupled from the database, we can create classes AbstractModel and CityModel and Queries and FirebaseAdapter so finally we can do something like

```
val city = Cities("BJ")
```

instead of lengthy code above.
Eventually I see that problem is we need to create our own ORM for using Firebase for every project. Or is there simpler solution? Do some existing ORMs work with Firebase? I did some research, however Stackoverflow policy prohibits to post trademarks into the question.

Comment: Did you check out the [Firebase Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#kotlin+ktx_4) where they show reading firebase data into objects like this `val post = dataSnapshot.getValue<Post>()`. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. So in your example, I would hide all the listeners in Adapter or base entity of ORM. Instead of listeners, I would like to operate just with objects of models: post.text = "new post". Log.i(post.text). The last line is the only thing I would like to see in the code. So I don't do post = Firestore.collection("posts"). get().addOnSuccessListener{document Snapshot -> etc etc}

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking but you don't need to lean on ORM as Firebase has built in features to map data to objects as shown the documentation. In other words you don't need ORM at all for most use cases, but it's hard to say for sure because we don't know about your specific use case.

Comment: The question is rather not about specific case. Instead it is more general: how to set up an ORM for the Firebase (for any project using Firebase because almost any project with remote database needs ORM). There is no question about whether we need ORM or not: definitely we need it. When you say that Firebase can map data to objects - it is not enough. The main principle of ORM is to implement loose coupling, so in the worst case e. g. we can replace FIrebase later with another database and our object structure and all the queries in controller will remain unchanged.

Comment: Understood. SO is a programming specific forum - asking *how to set up an ORM for the Firebase* is a very general topic and not well suited for SO. Take a look at[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in particular [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you have a specific coding question we are happy to help! Post your code and we'll take a look.

Comment: If you are referring me to "how to ask a question" section, please specify what exactly you didn't understand in the question? It seems like we are going to nowhere... I don't agree with you if you say that "how to set up an ORM for the Firebase" is not a question for SO. If you ask about specific code, let's take a line from your link e. g. database.child("users").child(userId).setValue(user). And the question is how can I adjust this code to make it loose coupled with Firebase, so the query text remains unchanged when I get rid of Firebase and transfer to another database?

Comment: I understand that I can write a separate adapter and class for ORM by myself, to make it loose coupled. But is it worth spending time? Because maybe there is existing solution - ORM that works with Firebase? Or does Firebase per se provide something more loose coupled rather than example from your link?

Comment: All I can tell you is that open ended questions like *how do I* or *what's the best solution for...* is not a good fit for SO as this forum is for coding specific issues; write some code and when it doesn't work, post a question about it. From the link **When asking a question, people will be better able to provide help if you provide code that they can easily understand and use to reproduce the problem**. Asking *how to use Firebase built-in features* is a very open ended. non-specific question and would require a LOT of documentation. Post some code describing what's being asked!

Comment: sure thing, I edited the question

Comment: WAY better question so I upvoted it. Something like this `val city = Cities("BJ")` may be problematic due to the asynchronous nature of Firebase. The Firebase code in the question correctly handles that - it waits for a response from Firebase (the data) and then acts on it - that's good, async code. However, the `Cities("BJ")` doesn't really lean toward that same process as it's expecting the var to me initialized immediately. Make sense?

Comment: Thanks for that. Cities is a custom defined class by me, with a constructor taking id of a document and returning city object with the same fields (properties) as in cities collection in Firebase. So all the asynchronous logic can be implemented inside of the functions of Cities class. E. g. Cities,get(documentId) will call db.collection("cities").document(documentId).get().addOnSuccessListener { documentSnapshot -> val city = documentSnapshot.toObject<City>()} Also, we can make Cities (or its parent abstract class of interface Model) to return Task object

Comment: if we need, so we can call addOnSuccesslistener in the main function. Or, we can call "await" every time inside of Cities functions, then in the main code (that is using Cities) we don't care about asynchrouns, so the code is just run consequently step by step. Overall, I don't see a problem for Firebase to be asynchronous to set up ORM there

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty good solution for .NET :
[Firestore.ORM](https://github.com/SecurEat/Firestore.ORM)

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion) also, please show how to use it to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35821617)